# Laravel Ajax posting data into the database

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

```
This is my index.php

    <div class="container">
    <h1>Drink A Coffee today</h1> <hr>
       <h2>Coffee Orders</h2>
    <ul id="orders">
    <p><li class="highlight"></li></p>
    <p><li class="highlight"></li></p>
    </ul>

    <h4>Add a Coffee Order</h4>

    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'index', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
     <div class="form-group" role="form">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="drink">Drink:</label>
        <input id="drink" type="text" name="drink" class="form-control">
    </p>
    <p>
        <button id="add-order" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Add!</button>
    </p>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Below is my controller

```
public function makeOrder() {
      $post = Request::all();

      if (Request::ajax()) {
        $order = new Order;

        $order->name = $post['name'];
        $order->drink = $post['drink'];

        $order->save();
        $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Option created successfully',
        );

        return Response::json( $response );
      }
    }

//Below is my Route

Route::post('index', 'MakeOrderController@makeOrder');
```

then my Ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#add-order').click(function(e) {
        e. preventDefault();
        //setting variables based on the input fields
        var inputName = $('input[name="name"]').val();
        var inputDrink = $('input[name="drink"]').val();
        var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        var data = {name:inputName, drink:inputDrink, token:token};

        var request = $.ajax({

            url: "index",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType:"html"
            });

            request.done(function( msg ) {
                var response = JSON.parse(msg);
                console.log(response.msg);
            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        });



});
```

But any time i try to submit, nothing happends and when i inspect element, i get this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
Request failed: error"

Comment: Please reformat this mess.

Comment: Can you post any messages you are getting in the Laravel log file? This should be in storage/logs

Comment: @DanWhite i think it is ok now?

Comment: @DavidStromberg Please nothing happeneds and laravel does not show any error too but when i inspect element i found "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" then below it,  "Request failed: error"

Comment: In your AJAX script, can you try changing the dataType to 'json'?

Comment: @David Stromberg i have but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I see it now. In your AJAX data, you are sending 'token', but Laravel is expecting this parameter to be named '_token'.

You can make it easier on yourself by just using jQuery's serialize() function on the form, instead of retrieving each field as a variable. Ex:

```
var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
```

Instead of var inputName, var inputDrink, etc

Comment: like so : `var data $(this).closest('form').serial
  var token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();`

Comment: Double check that 'var data' line. You're currently missing an =, and you need to call 'serialize()', currently just says 'serial'. And you can remove the 'var token' line as well. Otherwise should be good.

Comment: After trying, it wanted to submit  but still nothing happens.

Comment: Are you receiving the same error in the Javascript console? The 500 error should indicate that some error is occurring within the Laravel code, which should result in that error being logged. Please double check your Laravel logs to ensure that logging is turned on, and see if an error appears there. Without knowing what error is being thrown, it will be difficult to debug this further.

Comment: Ok i see.  The logg error says `Local. ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exeption\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController' not found ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\AjaxLav5.0\app\Http\Controllers\PagesController.php: 11 `

Comment: Is that the most recent error in the log (most recent is at the bottom of the file)? It seems unrelated to the MakeOrderController that was specified in your original post.

Comment: Yes that is the most recent error.  So how do i fix that error? Please you can read through my code again or probably copy them and try it urself if possible.